# Wordpress. Как поменять местами элементы на странице записи?

Tags: wordpress

На странице с записью в шаблоне wordpress выводится сначала картинка, затем заголовок, затем все остальное. Как можно и где именно поменять местами картинку и заголовок? Чтобы сначала шел именно заголовок записи, затем картинка и все остальное. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Это зависит от структуры шаблона. Обычно разметка постов находится в файле single.php.

Ищите там такие куски кода как:

```
<h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
```

Так выводится заголовок.

И что-то типо

```
<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $page->ID, 'thumbnail'); ?>
```

Так выводится миниатюра. Когда это найдете - просто меняйте местами